# Android studio External Storage using bluetooth problem

Tags: android, arduino

I'm trying to save data from arduino board to External Storage in my phone using bluetooth. 
actually, I can find a file in my phone but my problem is I can only find the last value, this is my andoid code:

```
    bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                DataStringIN.append(readMessage);

                int endOfLineIndex = DataStringIN.indexOf("#");

                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                    String dataInPrint = DataStringIN.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                    IdBufferIn.setText("Dato: " + dataInPrint);
                 //   savefile(fileName,dataInPrint);
                   String state;
                   state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                   if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                       File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                       File Dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAirfile");
                       if (!Dir.exists()) {
                           Dir.mkdir();
                       }
                       File file = new File(Dir, "MysensorData.txt");
                       String data = dataInPrint.toString();
                       try {
                           FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                           fileOutputStream.write(data.getBytes());
                           fileOutputStream.close();
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"saved!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                   }

                    DataStringIN.delete(0, DataStringIN.length());

                }
            }
        }
    };
```

and my arduino code is a simple communication.

thanks guys and sorry for my eng :p